# Java apps (based on JSwing) performance consuming?

Tags: java, performance, swing

I'm new to Java Programming. Recently I'm developing a mini game with JSWing. However, after coding for awhile the in-game FPS dropped terribly. When I tracked it on Task Manager I had result like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me what's wrong? I only used loops, JLabel with icons, Paint Graphics methods, mouseMotionEvent in my code.

Here is the code in the main game

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Game extends JPanel {


    int numb = 2;
    int pts = 5;

    Kitty[] Kitties = new Kitty[4];

    public Game() {




        for (int i = 0; i < Kitties.length; i++)
            Kitties[i] = new Kitty();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        BufferedImage img = null;

        try {
        img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("city.jpg"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("java io");
        }


        graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);


        //paints square objects to the screen
        for (int i = 0; i < numb;i++) {
            Kitties[i].paint(graphics);
        }
    }

    public void update(TheJPanel frame) {

        if (frame.a >= 0 && frame.a < 500) numb = 2;
        if (frame.a>= 500) numb = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i< numb; i++) {

                int disty = 500 - Kitties[i].squareYLocation; 
                int distx = Kitties[i].squareXLocation - frame.x;
                if ( Kitties[i].squareYLocation < 600 && disty <= 5 && disty >= -80 && distx < 260 && distx > -100){
                    frame.a +=pts;
                    if (Kitties[i].kittype == 6) frame.a += pts;
                    if (frame.a >= 500) {
                        Kitties[i].fallSpeed = Kitties[i].FallSpeedlvl2();
                            pts = 10;
                    } 
                    Kitties[i].squareYLocation = -200;
                    Kitties[i].generateKittype();
                    Kitties[i].generateRandomXLocation();
                    Kitties[i].generateRandomFallSpeed();



                    frame.point.setText("Point:" + String.valueOf(frame.a));
                    frame.lives.setText("Lives:" + String.valueOf(frame.count));
                }


        if(Kitties[i].squareYLocation > 610){
            frame.count--;

            Kitties[i].generateKittype();
            Kitties[i].generateRandomXLocation();
            Kitties[i].generateRandomFallSpeed();
            Kitties[i].squareYLocation = -200;

        }
        if (Kitties[i].squareYLocation >=605) frame.catFall(Kitties[i].squareXLocation);


        if(Kitties[i].squareYLocation <= 610){

            Kitties[i].squareYLocation += Kitties[i].fallSpeed;
        }


        }


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Game game = new Game();
        TheJPanel frame = new TheJPanel();


        frame.add(game);


        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Saving kitties");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        while (frame.count>0) {
            game.update(frame);

            game.repaint();

            Thread.sleep(4);


        }

        if (frame.count == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost!", "Game over!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            game.setVisible(false);
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            frame.bask.setVisible(false);
            frame.background.setVisible(false);
        }



    }
}
```

Here is the code for the main Jframe

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Imba Store
 */
public class TheJPanel extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener {

    protected int x;
    protected int a = 0;
    protected int count = 20;
    protected JLabel bask = new JLabel();
    protected JLabel background = new JLabel();
    protected JLabel point = new JLabel();
    protected JLabel lives = new JLabel();
    Timer fall;
    protected int time =0;

    public TheJPanel() {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        InitContent();



    }



    protected void InitContent() {
        Icon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("basket.png"));
        bask.setIcon(img);
        Icon themes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("city2.png"));
        background.setIcon(themes);
        background.setBounds(0, 699, 1000, 300);
        point.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 35));
        point.setText("Point:" + String.valueOf(a));
        point.setBounds(20,908,240,50);
        point.setForeground(Color.white);
        lives.setBounds(800, 908,200,50);
        lives.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 35));
        lives.setForeground(Color.white);
        lives.setText("Point:" + String.valueOf(count));
        point.setOpaque(false);
        add(point);
        add(lives);
        add(bask);
        add(background);
        bask.setSize(400,148);    
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent me)
    {
        x = me.getX();




        background.setBounds(0, 699, 1000, 300);
        bask.setBounds(x, 700, 400, 148);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent me)
    {

    }

        public void catFall(int getX){
        Icon fell = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("kitty-fall.png"));
        JLabel fellcat = new JLabel();
        fellcat.setIcon(fell);
        fellcat.setBounds(getX, 760, 220, 220);

        add(fellcat);


        add(background);
            fall = new Timer(1500, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               getContentPane().remove(fellcat);



            }
            });
        fall.setRepeats(false);
        fall.start();    
    }

}
```

And this is the class for the falling cats

```
    package game;

/**
 *
 * @author Imba Store
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public final class Kitty extends JLabel {

    protected int squareXLocation;
    protected int squareYLocation = -200;
    protected int fallSpeed = 1;
    protected int kittype;
    Random rand = new Random();


    public int generateRandomXLocation(){
        return squareXLocation = rand.nextInt(800);
    }



    public int generateRandomFallSpeed(){
        return fallSpeed = rand.ints(3, 4).findFirst().getAsInt();
    }

    public int FallSpeedlvl2() {
        return fallSpeed = rand.ints(3,7).findFirst().getAsInt();
    }

    public int generateKittype() {
        return kittype = rand.ints(1,8).findFirst().getAsInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        BufferedImage thugcat = null;
        try {
        img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("kitty.png"));
        thugcat = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("thug-kitty.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Java IO");
        }
        if (kittype == 6) {
            g.drawImage(thugcat, squareXLocation, squareYLocation, null);
        }
        else g.drawImage(img, squareXLocation,squareYLocation,null);

    }


    public Kitty(){
        generateRandomXLocation();
        generateRandomFallSpeed();
        generateKittype();
    }
```

Comment: I want to see your code.

Comment: I updated the code as your demand please help

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler?

Comment: I don't know it, what is it?

Comment: Run your application with a profiler. A profiler is similar to what you see on Task manager, but a lot more detailed. It will show you exact number of objects created, size of each object, memory usage, how much time is spent per method, how many threads are created, how many threads are blocked etc.. I would recommend to go with JProfiler.

Comment: Well thanks a lot but can anyone check out my code?

Comment: Dumping a bunch of code into [SO] and expecting people to sift through it for some vaguely specified performance issue is not really what [SO] is for and even if someone did it for you, it's not likely to help anyone else which is the purpose of the site. Just try a profiler and if you have specific problems there, ask a question about that.

Comment: Questions like this are a good fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    BufferedImage img = null;

    try {
    img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("city.jpg"));
```

Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent(...) not paint(). The first statement should then be super.paintComponent().

A painting method is for painting only. Don't do I/O in the painting method. This will cause the image to be read every time you repaint the panel.

```
Thread.sleep(4);
```

Sleeping for 4ms is not enough. That will attempt to repaint 250 times a second which is too often. There is no need for the frame rate to be that fast.

```
Kitty[] Kitties = new Kitty[4];
```

Variable names should not start with an upper case character. Most of your names are correct. Be consistent!

```
point.setBounds(20,908,240,50);
```

Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Set a layout manager for you background and then add the components.

```
public int FallSpeedlvl2() {
```

Methods should NOT start with an upper case character. Again, most are correct. Be Consistent!!!

Comment: Thank you man, I/O in painting methods was crucrial mistake, my program is a lot better now.